# Regex to find a string after the last colon

Tags: java, regex

Here is some sample input:

```
<210>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x55): double
 <ae>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x24): long int
 <b5>   DW_AT_name        : int
```

I want to extract the string that represents the actual type. So my output would be:

```
double
long int
int
```

Here is the regex I have so far (double escaped because it's in Java):

```
.*DW_AT_name.*:\\s*([^:&&\\S]*)\\s*
```

It works for the `int`, but it doesn't work for the other two. I think the best solution is to basically say 'get everything after the last colon' but I'm not sure how. Note that it must also include the `DW_AT_NAME` stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need no regex for this:

```
String yourString = "<210>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x55): double";
String result;
if (yourString.contains("DW_AT_name")) {
    int lastIndex = yourString.lastIndexOf(":");
    result = yourString.substring(lastIndex + 1).trim();
} else {
    result = "ERROR"; // or handle this however you want
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Simply find the last `:` and take everything after that. Then trim it to remove leading and trailing whitespace.

> I edited my question, it needs to also check for DW_AT_name. String split wont [sic] do that.

Just use `contains`, then. (edited answer)

Comment: I edited my question, it needs to also check for DW_AT_name. String split wont do that.

Comment: Might be better to use `String.lastIndexOf` instead of splitting (since you only care about the last token, anyways)

Answer (score 0):

This regexp `^.*DW_AT_name.*:\s*(.+)$` does the job as just tested on [regexplanet](http://fiddle.re/6qm6a).

Answer (score 0):

```
String type = str.replaceAll(".*:(?=[^:]+$)", "");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354662/regex-to-find-string-after-last-colon/17354682#comment25183234_17354682

Answer (score 0):

Try the next:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = 
    "<210>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x55): double\n" + 
    "<ae>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x24): long int\n" + 
    "<b5>   DW_AT_name        : int";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*DW_AT_NAME.*:\\s*([^:]+)$", 
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(text);
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("$1"));
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
double
long int
int
```