# Regex Colon String 2Colons

Tags: regex

How to get the string after 2 colons

```
:somelongstring::123abc:
```

how to get only the string `123abc`

i tried this: [Regex to find a string after the last colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354662/regex-to-find-a-string-after-the-last-colon)

Comment: or `:([^:]+):$`

Comment: @maraca This will grab the string after `:` and not `::` as OP requested.

Comment: @MarounMaroun after the 2nd last `:`, why else would he link a regex to find the last colon? It would match 123abc too.

Comment: Maybe people learning regex should try https://regex101.com/, first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you just want this:

```
"::(\w+)"
```

Comment: What's the `@` and `"` for? And why are you escaping the `:`?

Comment: `@` is used in c# anytime your using the `\\`` char in a string, and im escaping them because 1. its harmless and 2. there are certain scenarios in regex where `:` is special, like in `(?:`

Comment: **1.** You assume OP is using C#. **2.** There's no need at all to escape `:` here, why do you care about other cases that don't exist here?

Comment: like i said, its harmless. Also OP never stated any language.

Comment: But it's not a good practice. It's harmless to add `$$$$` at the end as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to find anything that is after double colon "::" and before single colon ":", as it is in your example.
You could use this regex:

```
regex = "::(.*):";
```

This basically tells: Give me everything that starts with "::" and ends with ":" but without those start and end characters.

Comment: What if the string is `:somelongstring::123abc:123abc:`?  Do we want to match one `123abc` or both?  (Your regex will match both.)

Comment: @JoeC You are definitely right. My regex would match both (123abc:123abc), and that is because regex is 'greedy' and it will try to match as much text as possible. Well, this is now a problem of defining what exactly we want to match, but I get your point.